# Count specific items separately in 1 cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I need a formula like COUNTIF for this problem.

Forexample:
I write ''a, b, c, d, d'' in 1 cell, but want them to be counted separately like this:

a -> 1

b -> 1

c -> 1

d -> 2

I tried with COUNTIF formula, but it only counts the exact item name added within the formula. If I add space or comma it doesn't work.

Hope there's a solution
thanks :)

Comment: Will your data always consist of single characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Write this formula in D1 & Fill it down:*

```
  =SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,LOWER(C1),"")))/LEN(LOWER(C1)))
```

**Note,**

1. If alphabets are in CAPITAL Letters in A1 don't use LOWER with C1.
2. *adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: .............very nice....................

Comment: Glad to help U @SunnyS-h, Keep asking.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
a, b, c, d, d
```

in **A1**, fill **B1** through **B4** with:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",""))
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"b",""))
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"c",""))
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"d",""))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To do counting for more than one cell, replace the **A1** in the formula with **A1 & CHAR(1) & A2**.

For many cells *(like **A1** through **A30**)*; replace **A1** in the formula with something like:

```
TEXTJOIN(CHAR(1),TRUE,A1:A30)
```

Comment: I tried this formula, and it seems I can only do it with a single cell. Is it possible to use this formula, where I mark multiple cells for example:

cell A1: a, a, b, b

cell A2: a, b, c, d

cell A3: d, d, d, d

Result:

A = 3

B = 3

C = 1

D = 5

Something like this. And is it possible to do it with names? Count names of people with comma, and added in multiple cells?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SunnyS-h  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: So something like this? =LEN(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(1),TRUE,A1:A30))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(1),TRUE,A1:A30),"a",""))

Comment: @SunnyS-h  yes................give it a try